# Adding image to SVG path

Tags: css, svg

I found some cool SVG code **[from](https://keithclark.co.uk/articles/practical-css-parallax/)** and started trying things out. Now I cleared up most of the random code but now I want to add an image on the grey block, but cannot seem to get it to work. I tried a few tips from StackOverflow already like adding random classes to it and creating extra id's in the code but it still won't work. I would like to create something like **[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/26Wge.jpg)**.

```css
.slide {
      position: relative;
      padding: 8% 0;
    }
    
    .slide__image svg {
      display: block;
      width: 100%;
      max-width: 560px;
      margin: auto;
    }
    .slide__bg {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      z-index: -1;
    }
```

```html
         <svg>
              <g id="p">
                <path opacity=".2" d="M0 2h252s-3.3 40.7-2.7 128.3C249 216 252 272 252 272s-88-2-124.3- 
    2C91.3 270 0 272 0 272V0z"/>
                <path fill="#f4f3f1" d="M0 0h248v270H0z"/>
                <path fill="#4f5150" d="M8 10h233v203H8z"/>
              </g>
              <g id="polaroid">
                <use xlink:href="#p" transform="rotate(15)" x="175" y="50"/>
                <use xlink:href="#p" transform="rotate(-5)" x="5" y="25"/>
              </g>
          </svg>
```

Thanks for looking at the question!

Comment: Hello. The most likely reason you are not getting answers is because your question is unclear. Try to read it as someone random on Internet -- does it explain what you're trying to do? Even after reading the entire article you linked to? An SVG code snippet together with some CSS are not indicative of a parallax effect necessarily, and that's some of the problem I see with your question -- it isn't even clear whether the SVG is crucially part of some HTML application, or if the entire effect is done _in_ the SVG code (which doesn't look to be the case). Edit your question, please.

Comment: Something like this https://imgur.com/a/j2GdTKn @amn, the entire effect is done in the svg code

Comment: And where are your images? How many? Should it be animated? Your question leaves so much out I am not even sure where to start.

Comment: Ehm just 1 images located in my images folder ./images/pic1.jpg like that and these images can just be still so no animations.

Comment: Ok, I understand. Where is the rest of your application code? Is what you posted all of it? You have a stylesheet that references classes like `slide` and others, and I don't see any elements that have that class. Have you omitted something or what does the stylesheet apply to?